# Is it possible to get a range that is calculated from a formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible to get a range that is calculated from a formula? For example...

```
=MATCH("TEST",INDIRECT("C8"),0)
```

where C8 = A43:A

C8 uses the following formula, `="A"&C6&":A"`

A43 is being calculated using a MATCH function which resides in cell C6.

Comment: What do you mean? What is "getting" the range? Drop the quotes around C8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
=MATCH("TEST",INDIRECT("A"&C6&":A"),0)
```

with C6 merely containing a formula that returns, for example, `43`.